# Deal with Core Data objects between views with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to send coreData to another view controller when selecting row from UITableViewthrough `didSelectRowAt` function.
Moving to another view controller through `navigationController?.pushViewController` in `didSelectRowAt` works, but I don't know how to send core data specifically.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984011/passing-core-data-objects-to-another-view-controller-when-selecting-row-from-uit)
almost matches what I'm trying to do,
but I don't know how to pass data if I'm not using the storyboard and programmatically load views using navigationController.

Specifically, I want to access and modify the cordData sent from the first controller from the second controller.

This is my code so far.

#### First View Controller

First VC contains table view

```swift
var items = [Item]() // this is coreData variable

...
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        items = DBManager.share.fetchItems()
        homeTableView.reloadData()
    }

extension FirstVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeTableCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        let newItem = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.homeCellTitle.text = newItem.title
        cell.homeCellPrice.text = newItem.price
        cell.homeCellPost?.text = newItem.post
        
        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = self.items[indexPath.row]

        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC else {return}
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

#### Second View Controller

```swift
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var selectedItem: Item?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       // I don't know this part.
    }
}
```

#### DBManager

handling coreData

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DBManager{
    static let share = DBManager()
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "RC_week3")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }) //completion Handler
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    lazy var context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    func saveContext () {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do{
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchItems() -> [Item]
    {
        var Items = [Item]()
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Item.description())
        
        do{
            Items = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Item]
        }catch{
            print("fetching error")
        }
        return Items
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObject` instances are reference types, just hand the instance over after instantiating the controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = self.items[indexPath.row]

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
        vc.selectedItem = selectedItem // <-- here pass the data
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
```

Side note: `guarding` the controller it not necessary as the storyboard cannot be modified at runtime. If the code crashes it reveals a **design** mistake.

And if you replace `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` with `NSFetchRequest<Item>` you get rid of the type cast.

```
 func fetchItems() -> [Item]
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: Item.description())
        
        do {
            return try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print("fetching error", error)
            return []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  this is a quite simple solution but I've struggled so far.